# SwipeToDeleteCallback - Not working as espected

Tags: java, android, swipe

I'm implementing swipe to delete in RecyclerView but I've notice that is not working as espected.

When the app launch for first time, items are collected from the db and polulated, when I swipe works fine. After thar if I add an item to the list (also to the db) I'm recovering all items again from the db and recreating the adapter, but if I swipe one element, the size of the adapter in SwipeToDeleteCallback doesn't match with the database items, so I'm getting an IndexOutOfBounds error.

Can you help me? I don't know what's wrong...

```
    public SwipeToDeleteCallback(RecyclerviewAdapter adapter) {
        super(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT);
        mAdapter = adapter;
        icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mAdapter.getContext(), R.drawable.ic_delete);
        background = new ColorDrawable(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        mAdapter.deleteItem(position);
    }

    public void deleteItem(int position) {
        mRecentlyDeletedItem = vehiculos.get(position);
        mRecentlyDeletedItemPosition = position;
        vehiculos.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        showUndoSnackbar();
    }

    RecyclerviewAdapter recyclerviewAdapter = new RecyclerviewAdapter(context);
    recyclerviewAdapter.setVehiculosList(vehiculos);
    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new
        ItemTouchHelper(new SwipeToDeleteCallback(recyclerviewAdapter));
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recycler);
    recycler.setAdapter(recyclerviewAdapter);
```

This is the code I've follow:

https://medium.com/@zackcosborn/step-by-step-recyclerview-swipe-to-delete-and-undo-7bbae1fce27e

```
    vehiculos = new ArrayList<Vehiculo>();
    Database dbHelper = new Database(context);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = new String[]{
        Database.SQL_FIELD_MATRICULA,
        Database.SQL_FIELD_ETIQUETA,
        Database.SQL_FIELD_DESCRIPCION
    };
    Cursor c = db.query(Database.SQL_TABLE_MATRICULAS, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
        Vehiculo vehiculo = new Vehiculo(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Database.SQL_FIELD_MATRICULA)), c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Database.SQL_FIELD_ETIQUETA)), c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Database.SQL_FIELD_DESCRIPCION)));
        vehiculos.add(vehiculo);
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
```

Comment: please add the code you use for " recovering all items again from the db and recreating the adapter"

Comment: @0X0nosugar Done! The recreation of the adapter is the las piece of code from the first post. When new SwipeToDeleteCallback(recyclerviewAdapter) is called recyclerviewAdapter size is correct.

Comment: Sorry, since I can't see the whole workflow of your app, I can't tell what's wrong. The individual pieces look harmless, but obviously they don't fit together well. If you share enough code so that I can copy-paste it and run it, then I'll look into the problem. BTW in this case it's very much ok if you don't post the whole app as long as the code still shows the problematic behaviour

Comment: @0X0nosugar I'm removing the item from the adapter in the RecyclerviewAdapter is that correct? Or should I delete it in the activity?

Comment: I've solve the issue, I was initializing the RecyclerView every time I reload the list (RecyclerviewAdapter recyclerviewAdapter = new RecyclerviewAdapter(context);). Removing it and moving it to the oncreate instead of asynctask works! Thank you @0X0nosugar for your help!

Comment: You're welcome :) And good luck with your project!